# CSV file to JSON using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am currently trying to convert a csv with 4 different fields to a json body for making an api call. The current csv looks like this:

```
firstname, lastname, email, login
Jake, Smith, jake.smith@example.com, jake.smith@example.com
John, Appleseed, john.appleseed@example.com, john.appleseed@example.com
```

I would like the json to look like this

```
{"profile": {"firstName": "Jake", "lastName": "Smith", "email": "jake.smith@example.com", "login": "jake.smith@example.com"}}
```

```
{"profile": {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Appleseed", "email": "john.appleseed@example.com", "login": "john.appleseed@example.com"}}
```

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial: https://medium.com/@hannah15198/convert-csv-to-json-with-python-b8899c722f6d

Comment: You want 2 different JSONs? Not an array of profiles?

Comment: @NYCCoder yes I want two separate json rather then an array of profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, not the best solution but works:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    json_data = df.loc[[i]].to_json(orient='records')
    json_data = json_data.strip('[]')
    x = json.loads(json_data)
    j = {'profile': x}
    print(json.dumps(j))
```

**Output:**

```
{"profile": {"firstname": "Jake", "lastname": "Smith", "email": "jake.smith@example.com", "login": " ake.smith@example.com"}}
{"profile": {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Appleseed", "email": "john.appleseed@example.com", "login": "john.appleseed@example.com"}}
```

Comment: awesome solution!

Answer (score -1):

1. import csv and import json packages
2. Create a file path to your CSV file: csvFilePath =
   ‘csv_file_name.csv’
3. Create a file path to your JSON file: jsonFilePath =
   ‘json_file_name.json’
4. Create an empty dictionary to store your converted JSON data: data =
   {}
5. Open and read the CSV:
   [image]
6. Open and read CSV file
7. Create a JSON file with the file path from step 3 to write converted data on
   [image]
8. Create new JSON file and write on it
9. Final code snippet
   [image]
   Final code example

Reference : https://medium.com/@hannah15198/convert-csv-to-json-with-python-b8899c722f6d

Comment: Not nice to post pics. Please paste everything as code.